# My output is empty when I print my data frame in streaming mode

Tags: file, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a folder that filled in streaming way with different txt files. I wrote a code that extract some IP informations and then put them in a data frame. (It works fine if I use it in non-streaming mode) The probelm is that, as I execute my code all outputs are empty!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.util.Try
/**
  * Created by saeedtkh on 5/24/17.
  */
object Main_ML_without_Streaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("saeed_test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
    conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    /////////////////////Start extract the packet
    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))

      val DStream = ssc.textFileStream("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test")
      val Row_DStream =DStream.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })

    Row_DStream.foreachRDD { DStream =>
          val dataFrame_trainingData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(DStream, customSchema)
          dataFrame_trainingData.groupBy("column1", "column2").count().show()
          /////////////////////end extract the packet


          val numFeatures = 3
          val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
            .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(numFeatures))
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////Model made
        }

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()


    print("Here is the anwser: *****########*********#########*******222")
  }
}
```

Here is the file content:

```
07:30:42.415558 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 163564797:163629957, ack 1082992383, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 65160
07:30:42.415558 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 65160:130320, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 65160
07:30:42.415558 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 130320:178104, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 47784
07:30:42.415660 IP 10.0.0.1.5001 > 10.0.0.3.53890: Flags [.], ack 178104, win 1, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 0
07:30:42.415708 IP 10.0.0.1.5001 > 10.0.0.3.53890: Flags [.], ack 178104, win 1051, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 0
07:30:42.415715 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 178104:195480, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 17376
07:30:42.415716 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 195480:260640, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 65160
07:30:42.415716 IP 10.0.0.3.53890 > 10.0.0.1.5001: Flags [.], seq 260640:325800, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 9762853 ecr 9762853], length 65160
```

**Update1:**
According to answer1 I got some errors:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
I should also mention that, each time I add new text files in the folder to process. So there is no old file there.

Could you please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: The program looks OK. The only suspicious point I see is that there are two `SparkContext` in action and maybe the data coming from one cannot be seen by the other (this is a speculation). To test that theory, I would first create the `sparkContext` and then attach the streaming context to it with the constructor: `val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(5))`

Comment: @massg: Thanks for your answer. You mean this format:
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5)).
I have tested it and It dose't work!  :(

Comment: If fails with the same problem when you use a single `sparkContext` ?

Comment: @maasg: Yes, I also delete the old txt files in streaming folder and then copy and paste new files  in it. But the problem sill exists!

Comment: @could you add some sample data? I'm curious to see why it fails. Also, what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @maasg: I have added the sample to the question. I use 10.11.8.

Comment: It works for me. Check out the notebook export of it: https://gist.github.com/maasg/9d9a410c8e7ddad23625ae293bd8def7

Comment: Check your logs for the following output: `New files at time` like in this entry:  `ui-logs-947238> [Tue May 30 2017 09:35:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)] [org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream] New files at time 1496129705000 ms:
file:/tmp/streaming/test/data2.txt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145425/discussion-between-saeed-talaee-and-maasg).

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I confirmed my suspicion hinted in the comments. The issue relates the multiple Spark Contexts on the same JVM (See below).

The correct way to initialize Spark, assuming a Spark version > 2.0 (and in this case 2.1.0), is using SparkSessionBuilder, like this:

```
val session = SparkSession.builder.
  master("local[*]")
  .appName("maasg_test")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Then we can create a `StreamingContext` using the underlying `SparkContext`, like this:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(session.sparkContext, Seconds(5))
```

Then the program works properly.

---

When using the configuration presented in the question, there are 2 `sparkContext` being initialized behind the scene. One implicitly created at this call:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
```

And a second one when we explicitly create it:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

It turns that the `SQLContext` created with the 2nd `SparkContext` can't see the data generated by the `StreamingContext` that has an unrelated `SparkContext` attached.

In the logs, this results in this kind of traces:

```
[org.apache.spark.executor.Executor] Exception in task 4.0 in stage 46.0 (TID 209). Stacktrace:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

One last word: The configuration setting: `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` may only be set to `true` in very specific cases, usually to run separate jobs in parallel.